# How do you turn on DND mode when camera is on?

Tags: macos, camera, focus

I'd like to find out how to turn on DND mode when camera is on. This is helpful whenever you're in a video meeting or sharing your screen not to be bothered with notifications or calls. I know it's possible to have an app specific Focus Mode for FaceTime, but I'm looking for something that activates DND across the board whenever any app such as Chrome, etc. is using the camera or the mic.